# Is it possible to ask a question about an answer of another question?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I found a linear algebra question and found Gone's answer interesting , but I didn't really understand it. I'd usually comment asking for a clarification, but apparently Gone who was once Bill has been suspended. So can I open a new question to ask about this answer?

Here is a link to the question : [Is there a quick proof as to why the vector space of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite-dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb)

Thank you

Comment: Note to readers: the OP [has posted said question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/293602/23500)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can ask a question that references another question or answer, but make your question self-contained in case the other question or answer gets deleted (which doesn't seem likely in this case). Describe, as best you can, what it is that is unclear or confusing about the referenced question or answer.